# Update jQuery Progress Bar even on Page Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, reload

I am currently working on a progress bar with jQuery that changes the inner progress bar according to checkboxes.

The script below works quite nicely except for the fact that when I reload the page, the progress bar is empty and the checkboxes are still activated.

This is probably due to the function not counting the number of checked checkboxes but uses the function checkbox.change() to start calculating.

My question now is how to configurate the script in order to update the progress bar even on page reload.

Thanks a lot in advance!

JQuery Script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var checkbox = $(":checkbox"),
    checkbox_length = checkbox.length;

    checkbox.change(function () {
        var that = $(this),
            progress = 0,
            checked_length = 0;

        if(that.is(':last-child')) {
              that.siblings().attr('checked', true);
        }

        checked_length = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
        progress = Math.round(checked_length / checkbox_length * 100);

        $('.bar').animate({'width' : progress + '%'}, 400);
        $(".progresstext").html(progress + '%');
        $.cookie('cookieProcessLevelProgress', progress, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
 <div class="meter"><div class="bar"></div></div><span class="progresstext"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really figure out a small part of your code, but what I pasted below is a good start... basically put the "setting" of the progress bar into a function (DRY) and then call it on page load, and on checkbox change :)

```
function setProgress( $checkboxes ) {

  var chk_length = $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length;
  var progress = Math.round(chk_length / $checkboxes.length * 100);

  $('.bar').animate({'width' : progress + '%'}, 400);
  $(".progresstext").html(progress + '%');

};

$(function() {

  var $checkboxes = $(":checkbox");
  setProgress( $checkboxes );

  $checkboxes.change(function(e) {
    $(this)
        .prevAll(":checkbox")
        .prop("checked",true)
        .end()
        .nextAll(":checkbox")
        .prop("checked",false);

    setProgress( $checkboxes );
  });


});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! However, somehow the progress bar doesn't change at all anymore. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/bSuSN/1/
Again, I don't know really what your cookie, or your sibling code is supposed to be doing, so that's kinda gone, you can create another function for getting/setting the cookies you need, too and keep it separate, and then call it as you like :) hope it helps!

Comment: ahem: in case you're new to JSFiddle, you must press "run" in the top-left to see the code working! :)

Comment: hm, the code doesn't wor. There is no progress visible when I check or uncheck the checkboxes. Instead, the meter looks kinds empty to me...^^' (I pushed the run-button of course)

Comment: oh so sorry you're absolutely correct! check this: - http://jsfiddle.net/bSuSN/4/ - one of the variables had changed... somehow :/

Comment: you're welcome, usually we ✓ the correct answer for people coming to see in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

For your information, you can associate HTML5 progress tag instead of associating jQuery with it. Suppose you use the `<progress>` tag, like `<progress value="6" max="10">` and then update the inner parameter using basic JavaScript. For me, the code looks somewhat like this:

```
<div id="content">
<progress value="2" max="10">
</div>
```

The last bit is onClick of checkbox, the value of x gets updated from 2 to 3, using x++. Next update the code using `document.getElementById("content").innerHTML` and that's it boom, it should work.

Happy coding.